# fread not loading in whats in my binary file?

Tags: c, arrays, file, fwrite, fread

Basically, I've written text to a file and heard that it is similar steps to fread the contents back into my array at the start of the program but nothing is read back in. Here is my code

```
void backUp(PAYROLL employee[], long int *pCounter)
{
    FILE *record;
        errno_t result = fopen_s(&record, "c:\\record.bin", "a+b");
    if (record != 0){
        fwrite(employee, sizeof(PAYROLL), 1 , record);
        fclose(record);
    }
}

void upload(PAYROLL employee[], long int *pCounter)
{

    FILE *record;
    errno_t result = fopen_s(&record, "c:\\record.bin", "r+b");
    if (record != 0)
    {
        fread(employee, sizeof(PAYROLL), 1, record);
        fclose(record);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hints:  how big is the PAYROLL array, and how big is the file after it's been written?

Comment: sizeof(employee) gives me 136,000,000 unless your talking about elements then the array has 1,000,000 elements and the file right now is 544 bytes from other runs

Comment: Check your return values, especially if you are looking for errors. Specfically of fopen and fread (duh).

Comment: Reading MS's documentation, which I can generally recommend, and especially when unexpected errors occur --https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx --, I cannot see a guarantee that the file pointer address argument passed to fopen_s wil be set to null when an error occurs. The site states clearly though "Always check the return value to see if the function succeeded before you perform any further operations on the file."

Comment: 136,000,000 -- I hope you are not working on RL data.

Comment: @PeterSchneider I used `ferror()` and got no error I think thats how it works? lol, no this is an assignment and I've got nearly it all done but files seems like the most challenging aspect of this it seems so varied

Comment: I cannot see how you used `ferror()` . Also I cannot see why you refuse to follow the rules laid out in the documentation. A recent study estimated a chance of 0.43 that a programmer's job will be automated soon (http://www.oxfordmartin.ox.ac.uk/downloads/academic/The_Future_of_Employment.pdf, appendix, no. 293). If you are not even able to follow simple instructions I think your personal chance is perilously close to 1.

Comment: More hints:  136,000,000 divided by 1,000,000 is 136.  136*4 is 544.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create and update a file in the root directory of the system drive, it is necessary to the execution of the program at a command prompt for the administrator.
So, the program have failed to do.

To do this, you want to change the creation of the file to the user directory, or there is a need to run the program by invoking the administrative command prompt.